# CSS positioning. (example included)

Tags: css

My css codes can be found here:
http://cssdesk.com/KGUfn

I'm trying to get the boxes at the bottom (icon1, icon2 and icon3) next to eachother and center them, but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Upvote for providing code to look at. Downvote for using Comic Sans :)

Comment: Not cosmic sans. :) "font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;" That website doesn't accept the fonts I believe.

Comment: You probably need to actually use font embedding. :) You might check whether you can get Cinzel Decorative from Google Fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently positioning `#icon-1` as `position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0;` and `#icon-2` as `position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;`

To get the effect you're describing, try using:

```
#icon-1, #icon-2, #icon-3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
#icon-1 { left: 50%; margin-left: -200px; }
#icon-2 { left: 50%; margin-left: -67px; }
#icon-3 { left: 50%; margin-left: 67px; }
```

Because you have 3 elements of `133px` width each, you have a total of `399px` in width (basically `200px`). Because of this, if you start with a position of `50%` within the parent element (hense `left: 50%` on each item) and then offset each one using margin - you get the layout you're after.

The `#icon-1` setting of `margin-left: -200px` accounts for `#icon-1`'s entire width, plus half the width of `#icon-2`. `#icon-2`'s offset of `-67px` sets its left edge at a distance of half it's own width to the left of the center (centering it). `#icon-3`'s offset of `67px` simply moves it to the right by an amount equal to half the width of `#icon-2` - making them non-overlapping.

For an example, here is an update to your original code: http://cssdesk.com/cXrsP

Also - your original `#icon-3` wasn't appearing because your css said `ackground-color: yellow` instead of **`b`**`ackground-color: yellow`

Comment: Perfect reply, but why don't we use icon3 on absolute position?

Comment: Ahh - because I originally answered the question strangely. :) I will update to reflect. `#icon-3` should definitely be absolutely positioned as well.

Answer (score 2):

Icon3 requires units on `right:` and you have a typo "ackground-color: yellow;"

```
#icon-3
    {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        right:300px;
        width:133px;
        height:152px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
```